# How to associate Article with multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, database-table

New to PHP/MySQL and building a CMS. I need to know how to associated an Article with multiple Categories eg "My Article 1" has to be in 3 categories and "My Article 2" has to be in only 2 etc.

It's basically just the table set up to begin with. Here's what I have:

```
Table = articles
Fields = id, publicationDate, title, summary, content

Table = categories
Fields = id, categoryTitle
```

I know a little about joins and relationships etc but I want to get this right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third table, called articles_to_categories or whatever, with two fields:

- article_id
- category_id

Add an entry for each article and category association.  Set the PK to be both columns.

Comment: I didn't know you could have two primary keys in one table

Comment: Not two primary keys... one key that uses both columns.  This is called a composite key.  Alternatively, you can add another column, but that is just a waste of space, since this table won't have anything else but these associations.

Comment: Okay I will try that now. As an example how would I return information in a SQL query eg. My Article 1 is in category 1, category 2 and category 3?

Comment: `SELECT categories.* FROM categories, articles_to_categories WHERE categories.id=articles_to_categories.category_id AND articles_to_categories.article_id=12345;`

Answer (score 2):

You need a many-to-many table that will link article ids to category ids

```
CREATE TABLE articles_categories (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    articles_id INT,
    category_id INT
) TYPE=myisam;
```

So for each category that you associate with an article you will need to insert a row into this table.

Perhaps something like:

```
$currentArticle = array('id' => 99, 'name' => 'Test Article');
$currentCategory = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'First Category');
mysql_query(sprintf('INSERT INTO articles_categories (articles_id, category_id) VALUES (%d, %d)', $currentArticle['id'], $currentCategory['id']));
```